# How do I enter a fixed username and password rather than requiring an input field in python?

Tags: python, input, passwords

I have a python script that prompts to enter a username and password. This works fine but I'm wondering if I can preset a fixed username and password in the file. Is there any way to easily edit the password prompt below to a fixed entry for username and password? s

```
    username = input("Enter the username: ")
    password = input("Enter the password: ")
```

Comment: You could just hardcode `username = "foo"` and `password = "keepthissecret"`. No need for `input()`. Usual warning about it really isn't secret if its in your python file apply.

Comment: Username = "David Boykin"

Comment: If this is the only input the script wants, another option is to create a file with the user name and password as the first two lines and pipe it in on the command line. `myscript.py < myidentity.txt`

Comment: @tdelaney - Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach sounds like a default parameter to a function. Something like:

```
def log_me_in(username=None, password=None):
    if username is None:
        username = input("Enter the username:\n>>> ")
    if password is None:
        password = input("Enter the password:\n>>> ")
    print("Logging in user {} with password {}".format(username, password))
```

This allows you flexibility to run `log_me_in("David", "$omething$ecret")` and not have to input those parameters every time. Alternatively you may omit those arguments and the default `None` values will be used (forcing you to type input during program execution).

Examples:

log_me_in()

```
Enter the username:
>>>Dave
Enter the password:
>>>pa$$word
Logging in user Dave with password pa$$word
```

log_me_in("Dave")

```
Enter the password:
>>> My Password
Logging in user Dave with password My Password
```

log_me_in("Dave", "Password")

```
Logging in user Dave with password Password
```

log_me_in(password="A secret")

```
Enter the username:
>>> Dave
Logging in user Dave with password A secret
```